# git clone doesn't download everything

Tags: git, branch, clone, commit

How can I download everything fom a repository using git clone? Folders that have a special symbol (shown below) aren't being downloaded.

[image: strange folders]

I looked around and saw this command but it didn't work out for me. What other options are there?

```
for remote in `git branch -r`; do git branch --track $remote; done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those look as if they are probably [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).  Assuming that's the case, you can either clone the repository like this:

```
git clone --recursive REPO_URL
```

Or, from inside the already cloned repository:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

In any case, definitely read the documentation I linked to to understand what is going on with submodules.