# Git Clone does not download all folders

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio-2019

When cloning either in VS or in Git Bash, two of the folders are not downloading.

This post looked helpful but I tried the answer and nothing changed: [git clone doesn't download everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713488/git-clone-doesnt-download-everything)

Here's a screenshot of the Repo files. The folders in green downloaded just fine. The ones in red didn't.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have checked out the correct branch? And do those folders contain anything?

Comment: Have you checked your `.gitignore` file? git also doesn't track an empty folders. These folders can also be a submodules for example

Comment: If the directories do not include any file (that git is tracking), they are not part of the revision.

Comment: @DavidG both folders contain projects and the related files. And the Branch dropdown is on the correct branch (on the https://dev.azure.com/... website.)  However, there is no mention of the branch in the clone URL.

Comment: Switch branches locally then `git checkout <branch>` from command line.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the folders in question are not in the gitignore folder, but that was a good question

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The gitignore file wouldn't stop files being downloaded, only added to the repo in the first place.

Comment: @David, that worked! "Switch branches locally then git checkout <branch> from command line"  Now the folders are in my local folder. But they are still not showing in the solution.

Comment: Not showing in the solution? Restart Visual Studio?

Comment: @DavidG yeah did that. But now that I look at the solution file, they are just not there. So it looks like I'll just add them manually.  If you want to add your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as correct. (It's odd. I thought I had already done that, but doing it again seemed to work.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have likely not checked out the branch that is showing in Azure Devops. You just need to switch branches. That can be done in your UI or from the command line:

```
git checkout <branchname>
```